# React Native : iOS build crash after upgrade project to 0.58.0

Tags: xcode, react-native, buddy-build

I am updated my project to **RN 0.58.0**. Android builds (simulator and release) are working but i have problem with iOS builds.
I am building iOS app on BuddyBuild.

Build is working on iOS simulator but not on BuddyBuild (release).

I get this error:

```
4245
    ✗ File /tmp/sandbox/59d38c98cef756000131c06c/bbbuild/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/MyApplication.app/main.jsbundle does not exist. This must be a bug with
4246
    ▸ Generating MyApplication.app.dSYM
4247
    ** BUILD FAILED **
4248
    The following build commands failed:
4249
        PhaseScriptExecution Bundle\ React\ Native\ code\ and\ images /tmp/sandbox/59d38c98cef756000131c06c/bbbuild/Build/Intermediates.noindex/MyApplication.build/Release-iphoneos/MyApplication.build/Script-00DD1BFF1BD5951E006B06BC.sh
4250
    (1 failure)
```

Help?

Comment: Which version of react-native were you on before?

Comment: @Andrew version 0.55.2

Comment: Have you tried building a `release` build locally? Are you using `react-native-sentry`?

Comment: @Andrew I am not using react-native-sentry. For building release build locally I got some error about linker: `library not found for -lRNFirebase
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Comment: If you are using Pods did you use the `xcodeproj` instead of using `xcworkspace`? `xcworkspace` should be used for any project with Pods, you may also need to update your Pods

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

react-native init whatever

cd whatever

react-native run-ios # this is not going to work, it will fail with your compilation error.

react-native run-ios # this will not work either, it will compile a lot more but then is going to run into some other issues.

pkill node

open -a Terminal "`react-native start --reset-cache`"

react-native run-ios # this time it should work

You're good to go!